# Android : Getting photos for contacts is not working

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application in which I am retrieving contacts for sync purposes and querying for getting the photos. Unfortunately, I am getting no photos from the method. I get the contact_id properly, but no photos. I have many contacts which have photos. Am I doing something wrong? There are no errors, just no photos.

Code :

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(cur!=null) {
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                   // System.out.println("Name is "+name);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);


                        assert pCur != null;
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            long contactId  = pCur.getLong(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
// Above also tried passing CONTACT_ID instead of _ID
                            System.out.println("Contact id is "+contactId);
                            try {
                                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId));

                                if (inputStream != null) {
                                    Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                                    if(photo!=null){
                                        System.out.println("Photo is not null");
                                    }
                                    // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                                    // imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                                    inputStream.close();
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          //  System.out.println("Phone number is "+phoneNo);
                        }


                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            cur.close();
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: if(photo!=null){
                                        System.out.println("Photo is not null");
                                    }
                                                                   instead of                                 if(photo!=null){
                                        System.out.println("Photo is not null");
                                    }
                                    // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                                    // imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

Comment: @Raj : What is the difference?

Comment: if bitmap is not null they only return else default image was displayed

Comment: @Raj : That is just commented out code, anyways, I don't even get the printout photo is not null.

Comment: Then check inputstream is null or not                        and close the inputstream outside of if conditon

Comment: @Raj : Inputstream is null... I am not getting inputstream as well. Do you know what is wrong? Please post an answer with code if that's the case. Thank you.

Comment: Not try with the code just oral thinking if u want the code then i will try ask quickly.